# What algorithm is the best for connecting users based on a set of criteria?

Tags: algorithm

For a school related assignment I am doing research on finding algorithms who could help connecting users based on a set of criteria.

Imagina we have a big box with thousands of users with criteria like popularity and location.

How will I be able to find a perfect match for a specific user? The goal is to connect people worldwide to unique people.

I am very new into algorithms and data structures. At this moment I think a optimization algorithm could help but I don't see a specific implementation.

I am curious what you think, guys! If you need some more information or do have questions, feel free to ask!

Greetz,

Bobby

Note; For now I labeled this question under 'algorithm', please let me know if I should add other labels for better finding!

Comment: look into dating sites... And how they do it..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the best algorithm, but that probably depends on the application. Here is what you could do:

1. Turn the properties of each user into a normalized array. E.g. if we have three properties: age in years, income in $, smoker (yes/no) then this could be transformed to `[age, income / 10000, smoker = no ? -5 : 5]`. So if one is a smoker and the other one isn't then it is about as bad as 10 years of age difference.
2. This gives a data point in a hyperdimensional grid for each user. Now we can just measure the distance (e.g. euclidean distance) between a user and his closest neighbours and then take the shortest one.